# How to disable Auto update of Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have self-hosted integration runtime.
"Edit integration runtime" in Azure Portal says that "Auto update" is "Enabled".
However I cannot change it to disabled. Schedule times are also gray and not editable.

Comment: auto-update to a new version is managed internally. You cannot change it.
The self-hosted integration runtime Auto update page in ADF portal shows the newer version if current version is old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Integration runtime tab under manage section and Edit your self hosted integration runtime . Go to Auto Update tab and select disable and click apply.

If the buttons are showing greyed out for you, it means you are lacking some required permissions. Check with your administrator if they can disable.

Here is a short video of the steps:

[image]